# determinant of SU(3) matrix

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, determinant

I don't understand the determinant condition on SU(3) group, broadly.

I know that the determinant of such matrices should be equal to 1.
But what is the real intention of that 1?

Is it the real number 1 i.e. 
$1+i 0$ ?

Or the determinant of such matrices is a complex number per se and the absolute value of this complex number is equal to 1?

Comment: SU(3) is a real Lie group, not a complex Lie group...

Comment: As far as I know the elements of the unitary matrices are complex? And SU(3) stands for "Special Unitary $3 \times 3$ matrices"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of any unitary matrix is a complex number with absolute value $1$. The special unitary matrices are the subgroup having determinant equal to $1$, i.e. $1+0\cdot i$.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, let $A\in \operatorname{U}(n)$ i.e. $A$ is a matrix in $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$  satisfying $A^*A=I_n$ where $A^*=\overline{A^T}$. So we have
$$1=\det(I_n)=\det(A^*)\det(A)=\vert \det(A)\vert$$
hence $\det(A)$ is a complexe number with absolute value $1$. Now it's easy to prove that the map $\varphi :\operatorname{U}(n)\to(\Bbb C^*,\times), A\mapsto \det(A)$ is a group homomorphism and we define the subgroup $\ker\varphi$ and we denote it $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ the set of matrices in $\operatorname{U}(n)$ with determinant equal to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to keep the matrices that preserve orientation and to ignore scaling.

Since every matrix, $M \in M^{3 \times 3}(\Bbb{R})$, has a determinant that is positive, negative, or zero This partitions the matrices into three chunks : those with negative determinant (which reverse orientation when they act), those which are singular, and those with positive determinant (which preserve orientation).

Also, we are not interested in scaling, so we can find an $\alpha$ such that $\det \alpha M \in \{-1,0,1\}$ so that the actions of the $\alpha M$ preserves volumes.  In fact, we imagine that we have collapsed the ray of matrices $\{\beta M : \beta \in (0,\infty)\}$ to the one with determinant $1$.

Comment: But $SU(3)$ consists of complex matrices...

Comment: @JasonDeVito ; SU(3) is a real Lie group.  As a manifold, it is $n^2-1$-dimensional.  I have no idea what SU(3) you're talking about.  There's a generalization involving a Hermitian matrix in GL($n$,$\Bbb{R}), but this seems irrelevant to the OP's question.

Comment: $SU(3)$ is a a real Lie group whole elements are complex matrices satisfying $A\overline{A}^t = \overline{A}^t A = I$ and $\det (A) = 1$.  I agree that it's 8 dimensional as a manifold.  But maybe I'm misunderstanding your objection.